# How to set CFBundleVersion (and/or) CFBundleShortVersionString programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am building a framework to be used with [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), and I want to reflect the pod version (same inside the .podspec) into the framework CFBundleVersion (and/or) CFBundleShortVersionString. So I want to implement a new "Build phase" that reads the current pod version from `.podspec` and changes the values from the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/agvtool.1.html) to update build number.
e.g:
agvtool new-version -all 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can also check manually for the info.plist file and alter it using the foundation Framework. Loading as a dictionary, alter the value and then saving it again.